# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\X] does not exist in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I have the following method for update my user entry(`SampleTypeController.php`).

```
public function edit(sType $sType)

    {

        return view('sampletypes.edit',compact('sType'));

    }

    

    /**

     * Update the specified resource in storage.

     *

     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request

     * @param  \App\inventory  $inventory

     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

     */

    public function update(Request $request, sType $sType)

    {

        try{

            request()->validate([

            'samp_name' => 'required',

            'samp_desc' => 'required',


        ]);

    

        $sType->update($request->all());

    

        return redirect()->route('sampletypes.index')

                        ->with('success','Sample Type updated successfully');
        }

        catch(Exception $e){

            return redirect()->route('sampletypes.index')

                        ->with('failed','An error occured.');
        }


    }
```

And this is my route

```
Route::resource('sampletypes', SampleTypeController::class);
```

Beginning of my `web.php`I even included

```
use App\Http\Controllers\SampleTypeController;
```

But whenever I tried to access the editing blade, It keeps giving me the following error

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\sType] does not exist.
```

Then I tried to change my route into this

```
Route::patch('/sampletypes/{id}/edit/', 'SampleTypeController@update')->name('sampletypes.update');
```

Still, I was getting the same error, I followed the same way for my previous blades, controllers, and routes, but for this, I'm getting the mentioned error.

Comment: probably you are using Laravel 8, if so then change `Route::resource('sampletypes', 'App\Http\Controllers\SampleTypeController');`

Comment: @sta Tried, still getting the same error

Comment: `sType` and `SampleType` are different